# Removing the rows from a table after closing the jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I had a jquery dialog in which there was "+" button which will add the rows and "bin" symbol which will delete the rows . All looks good till here but when i close and reopen the dialog its still having the added rows instead it should reset to only one row with "+" and "bin" symbol .

```
<table id="table1" style="table-layout: fixed" class="reptable">

    <tr class="firstclass" id="school0">
        <td ><input type="text" id="rollnum" name="rollnum" class="rollClass" maxlength="20"/></td>
        <td ><select id="school" name="school" multiple="multiple" style="width: 95px; size: 50px" size="3" class="schoolClass"></td>
        <td><img src="<c:url value="/images/add_small.png"/>" id="btnAdd1" class="addImg"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/delete_small.png" id="btnDelete1" class="delImg"/></td >
    </tr>

    <tr class="secondclass" id="college0">
        <td ><input type="text" id="rollnum" name="rollnum" class="rollClass" maxlength="20"/></td>
        <td ><select id="college" name="college" multiple="multiple" style="width: 95px; size: 50px" size="3" class="schoolClass"></td>
        <td><img src="<c:url value="/images/add_small.png"/>" id="btnAdd1" class="addImg"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/delete_small.png" id="btnDelete1" class="delImg"/></td >
    </tr>


$('#school-dialog').dialog({
    //autoOpen : true,
    height : 800,
    width : 950,
    modal : true,
    dialogClass : "schools",
    title : 'School and College',
    closeOnEscape : true,
    open : function(event){
        $('#school-dialog').show();
    },
    close : function(event) { 
        $("#school-dialog").dialog("destroy");
    }
});
```

Any help on this is appreciated .

Comment: If you want help you need to provide all relevant code. Unless you reset the content before opening same element nothing will have changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all the schools `class="school"`, and all the colleges `class="college"`. Then you can delete all but the first row of each with:

```
close: function(event) {
    $("#table1 tr.school:gt(0), #table1 tr.college:gt(0)").remove();
    $("#school-dialog").dialog("destroy");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it removed all the rows in the table . I can add n rows for school and n rows for college after closing and reopening a dialog it should show only one row for each . at the moment it was deleting all the rows in the tables .

Comment: Where does the question say one row for each? It just says "reset to one row".

Comment: I've updateed the answer to explain how to keep the first row of each type, by giving them a class.